# Error when using animation.py on Julia 1.5.2

Tags: python, julia, pycall

I use the first example of [this link](https://genkuroki.github.io/documents/Jupyter/20170624%20Examples%20of%20animations%20in%20Julia%20by%20PyPlot%20and%20matplotlib.animation.html) to make a videos. On my previous Julia version before I changed computer, which was I think version 1.2, this worked fine.
Now, everything works fine, until the last line

```
myanim[:save]("testvid.mp4",writer=mywriter)
```

To which I get the error message:

```
ERROR: PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'FileNotFoundError'>
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1123, in save
    with mpl.rc_context({'savefig.bbox': None}), \
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 249, in saving
    self.setup(fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 338, in setup
    self._run()
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 348, in _run
    self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/XX/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

Stacktrace:
 [1] pyerr_check at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/exception.jl:62 [inlined] 
 [2] pyerr_check at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/exception.jl:66 [inlined]
 [3] _handle_error(::String) at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/exception.jl:83
 [4] macro expansion at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/exception.jl:97 [inlined]
 [5] #110 at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:43 [inlined]
 [6] disable_sigint at ./c.jl:446 [inlined]
 [7] __pycall! at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:42 [inlined]
 [8] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{String}, ::Int64, ::PyObject) at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:29
 [9] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{String}, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,PyObject,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:writer,),Tuple{PyObject}}}) at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:11
 [10] #_#117 at /Users/XX/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/src/pyfncall.jl:86 [inlined]
 [11] top-level scope at REPL[137]:1
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

The exact same code ran perfectly in the former Julia version.

Comment: How did you upgrade from 1.2 to (I guess) 1.5? Did you reinstall all needed packages? Could you try rebuilding `PyCall`? For example like so: `using Pkg; Pkg.build("PyCall")`

Comment: Yes, I tried rebuilding PyCall multiple times.. Julia updated automatically when I changed computer, I just reinstalled all packages that I needed